# Booting for imaging

Tags: macos, terminal, network, switching

Our corp is implementing Macs for the first time.  We are using Casper to manage them.  Unfortunately our Computing Security folks will not allow a Mac Server with NetBoot on our network, which puts us in a real jam.  How do we boot up to get an image?

We are stuck using USB devices to boot from - a huge expense and a lot of trouble.  I would like to be able to boot to the Lion recovery partition and use Terminal to execute the Casper Imaging app from a remote share.  Is this possible?  What are the terminal commands to mount a remote windows share from the (non-writable) Recovery Partition?  If I can do that then we can at least get to our images without needing a 16GB USB stick loaded with the Mac OS.

It would be awesome to have a bootable ISO that would have a Mac runtime environment and network.  Is there anything like this?  No "WindowsPE" for Mac?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Tell your network people that you want a VLAN that you can use to image your macs on.  Chances are they're worried your net boot env will mess with existing machines on the network.  A VLAN would allow you to run your net boot stuff without affecting the rest of the network.  The problem with this method is that in order to image a machine you need to also place the target machine on the same VLAN.  Depending on your situation this might not be a problem.

At any rate, I think your network people are being lazy, this is an easy problem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

**If you opt for the sneaker-net method**, use an external **FireWire** hard drive, not a USB stick. Installs will be much quicker. Also, learn how to use [Target Disk Mode](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8443.html) with FireWire between a working Mac laptop and the target machine you want to re-image. This will save you a great deal of time.

[Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) and [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) are great and inexpensive third-party disk cloning and restore tools for Mac OS X.

Using a working Mac laptop with Target Disk Mode over Firewire, and a utility like Carbon Copy Cloner, gives you a "Windows PE" and much more.

Whether you can work out a network method or not, understanding FireWire external drives, Target Disk Mode, and the use of a Mac OS X disk cloning tool should be important parts of your IT support toolkit.

I also want to point out that you can use a SINGLE image for all Intel-based Macs, even if they are of many different models and model years. This is in sharp contrast to the Windows world where you need a different image for each make and model of PC and all the various network interface cards and variant hardware between them. None of this is necessary on the Mac platform.